# Export Webpart from Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way for one to export or save a webpart created in Visual Studio 2010 in such a way that it can be imported via the browser to a Sharepoint 2010 site? I am working on a development server and would like to migrate one of the webparts that I deployed there onto an active Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to do that. You can upload a webpart to the Webpart Gallery using the browser and you can import an instance of a webpart to a page through the browser. But your custom webpart is going to depend on either an ascx user control, a DLL, or both. And you won't be able to deploy these files using only the browser.

I suggest using the solution package created by Visual Studio 2010 and deploying that to your active SharePoint site.